# yarn dlx not found. Why?! How to run yarn dlx command?

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

I installed yarn by

```
brew install yarn
```

i try

```
yarn dlx storybook@latest upgrade
```

result:

```
yarn run v1.22.22
error Command "dlx" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en
```

yarn add or yarn install working correctly

Comment: You installed version `1.x` which doesn't have this command https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install

Comment: But I just installed yarn! I installed it with both npm and brew. So I must have an up-to-date yarn package if I just installed it. Thanks for the link, I'll give it a try.

Comment: No, it's not possible to install yarn version higher than 1.x from npm or brew

Comment: What's the point? Isn't that the most popular way to install yarn? Why are they giving away obviously outdated software? @Konrad

Comment: "*Modern releases of Yarn aren't meant to be installed globally, or from npm.*" - this is what they say, but I don't know why. They changed it with 2.x